# samba acces from external network

Tags: samba, port-forwarding

I successfully installed samba and created shared directory, that can be accessed from local network. My question is, how to access my shared directory from an external network (internet). I read somewhere that I should open ports on my router, so I did, I opened 139/TCP nad 445/TCP ports. What should I do next ? How can I for example mount my shared directory on different Ubuntu computer via my public ip address ?
Thanks for your responds.

Comment: You not only have to open ports, but you have to forward ports to the local IP address of the computer where you setup the samba server. This is more of a router and Network Address Translation (NAT) related question not specific to Ubuntu. I am voting to close it.

Comment: In addition to opening the ports on your router, there are a few other considerations.  Please review [https://serverfault.com/questions/105241/accessing-samba-shares-over-the-internet](https://serverfault.com/questions/105241/accessing-samba-shares-over-the-internet)

Comment: Also [https://superuser.com/questions/409222/use-windows-smb-to-share-folder-over-the-internet](https://superuser.com/questions/409222/use-windows-smb-to-share-folder-over-the-internet)